# SKAction waitForDuration() blocking SKAction sequence

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ SKAction.waitForDuration(1), SKAction.runBlock({ self.speed = 0; print("pause") }), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), SKAction.runBlock({ self.speed = realSpeed; print("resume") }) ]))
```

The last skaction does not get called.

But when I remove the second waitForDuration, the last skaction gets called.

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ SKAction.waitForDuration(1), SKAction.runBlock({ self.speed = 0; print("pause") }), SKAction.runBlock({ self.speed = realSpeed; print("resume") }) ]))
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node's `speed` property affects the execution speed of actions run on that node. From the docs,

> The default value is 1.0, which means that all actions run at their normal speed. If you set a different speed, time appears to run faster or slower for all actions executed on the node and its descendants. For example, if you set a speed value of 2.0, actions run twice as fast.

In your first `runBlock`, you are setting the `speed` property of `self` to 0. This causes the second `waitForDuration` action to run infinitely slow (assuming `actualDuration = duration/speed`).

Comment: please would you take a look at this question for me, I've been at it for a while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602058/how-to-interrupt-a-spritekit-sequence-of-actions-and-resume-as-if-there-was-no-i